# PHP Update for Radio buttons

Tags: php, forms, jquery-mobile, input, pdo

The radio buttons (gender and level) showing "undefined" when I press submit. I am using jQuery Mobile framework. The other fields that have `type=text` work fine. How do I insert value in the backend for these radio buttons? Would I need to set the value explicitly in PHP? (i.e. `if$_POST['gender'] == 'male'`)

**Somehow $_POST['gender'] and $_POST['level'] is not defining the variable. Only when there is only 1 radio button it works.**

```
 <form action="save.php" method="post">
        <label for="name">Name </label>
        <input id="name" type="text" name="name"/>

        <label for="city">City </label>
        <input id="city" type="text" name="city"/>

        <label for="lang_know">Language </label>
        <input id="lang_know" type="text" name="language"/>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="lang_level">Level</label>
            <fieldset id="lang_level" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <label for="okay">Okay</label>
            <input type="radio" id="okay" name="level" value="okay"/>
            <label for="good">Good</label>
            <input type="radio" id="good" name="level" value="good"/>
            <label for="great">Great</label>
            <input type="radio" id="great" name="level" value="great"/>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="gender">Gender</label>
            <fieldset id="gender" data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal">
            <label for="male">Male</label>
            <input type="radio" id="male" name="gender" value="male"/>
            <label for="female">Female</label>
            <input type="radio" id="female" name="gender" value="female"/>
            </fieldset>
        </div>

        <label for="age">Age </label>
        <input id="age" type="number" min=18 max=90 name="age"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Update"/>
    </form>
```

Save.php

```
<?php
    try{

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $city = $_POST['city'];
    $language = $_POST['language'];

    $level = $_POST['level'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];

    $age = $_POST['age'];
    $email = "lapm@gmail.com";

    $connection = new PDO ('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=tongue', 'web', 'lapming1');
    $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $connection -> setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    function save ($query, $email, $connect, $name, $city, $language, $level, $gender, $age) {
        $statement  =  $connect->prepare($query);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':email',$email, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':language', $language, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':level', $level, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':gender', $gender, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> bindParam(':age', $age, PDO::PARAM_STR, 127);
        $statement  -> execute();
    }

    $sql = 'UPDATE user
            SET name=:name, city=:city, language=:language, level=:level, gender=:gender, age=:age
            WHERE email=:email';
    $save = save ($sql, $email, $connection, $name, $city, $language, $level, $gender, $age);

    header ('Location:profile.php');

    $connection = null;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    };  
?>
```

Comment: Debug it by using var_dump($_POST); just before $connection,, see what is the put put in "gender" and "level" index of array

Comment: Give a "name" attribute to submit button and firstly check for if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ //all the code here};

Comment: @OM The Eternity, var_dump($_POST) says both variables is undefined... am I not defining it in the code for some reason?

Comment: The undefined error comes in new versions beacause they want the varabl;es to initialized or defined previously some where or tested before using it.... hence you need to keep this in mind

Comment: I am not recieving any undefined error with gender or level radio button

Comment: It seems to be the 'name=' that is causing the trouble.. when I only have 1 radio button, it works. But when I have two radio buttons with the same name, it doesn't work...

Comment: Thats the property Of Radio Button, its not the Problem. thats the way radio buttons work.. this is not the issue

Comment: then it must be mysql then... somehow I must not be defining the variable right... I am using VARCHAR(255) right now

Comment: No NOT AT ALL.. Mysql doesnt have any relevance to this problem do one thing create 2 test files with code you have herein one of html without ur jquery mobile framework and one save.php, in save.php only place a code var_dump($_POST); and execute the html file and see wat r u getting

Comment: I did that already. Still saying undefined.

Comment: And I cleared all my cache. I am using Chrome.

Comment: somehow $_POST['gender'] is not defining the variable. only when there is only 1 radio button it works..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the workaround that I wrote.

```
<fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
<legend>Gender</legend>
<input id="male" type="radio" name="male" value="male"/>
<label for="male">Male</label>
<input id="female" type="radio" name="female" value="female"/>
<label for="female">Female</label>
</fieldset>
```

save.php

```
//gender radio buttons
    $male = $_POST['male'];
    $female = $_POST['female'];

    if (isset($male)){
        $gender = 'male';
        };

    if (isset($female)){
        $gender = 'female';
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

For data to be transmitted properly on form elements you need to set the name attribute.

```
<input type="text" name="blarg" value="" />
```

This will come through to PHP as $_GET['blarg'] or $_POST['blarg'], respectively.

You should go through your form elements and add the *name* attribute to match the value of each *ID* attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why the radio buttons aren't working, they look right to me.

As for age, are you sure your browser supports input type="number"?

In any case, what does `print_r($_POST)` show?

Comment: when I run this instead of save.php, it says "undefined" for gender  <?php
 try{
 
 
 //radio buttons
 $gender = $_POST['gender'];

 echo $gender;
 
 }; 
?>

Comment: use var_dump($_POST); just before $connection and tell whats the put put array looks like

Comment: I just copied your HTML, made it post to itself, and print_r($_POST) showed the right variables. The only thing I can think of is that your browser is broken.

Comment: Can you post the scripts (jQuery includes, inline Javascript, etc) you have on the page?

Answer (score 0):

Ist try  `echo $gender = $_POST['gender'];`

if its working then echo your query

```
echo  $sql = 'UPDATE user
            SET name=:name, city=:city, language=:language,
            level=:level, gender=:gender, age=:age
            WHERE email=:email';
```

I hope this will help you in getting your desired result

Comment: its not the $sql problem. I did echo $gender, and it says undefined. I don't understand why it says undefined because it is defined.

Comment: I copy paste your code & everything working perfect, try to empty your  browser cache or test in another browser

Comment: If everything is working fine, then it must be jQuery Mobile script causing the problem I guess.

Comment: this doesnt have to do anythiong with ur mobile framework this is related to ur $_POST['gender'] identification... Your radio button value is not readable on ur out put... I have tried ur code And it is working fine, Press Ctrl+Shift+Delete(for windows only) to clear the cache